# How do I kill running dev_server?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ant

I'm using Google App Engine to create a site, and I am using Ant as my build system. Currently I am able to run my app using `ant runserver` and everything works fine... the first time. There is no way to stop that sever from command line, `Ctrl+C` only kills the batch job, not the forked dev_server. I can't run a new instance either, as the port is blocked. Currently I have to go and kill the process from the command line. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: For now I am using makeshift batch scripts that simply kill any tasks named `Java.exe`. Obviously not an optimal solution, but it's a temporary fix.

Comment: `jps` shipped with JDK lists all the java processes currently running. Adding some cli parameters gives you more details of the java processes. If your app doesn't have a management port that allows you to connect to it and send a shutdown command (like Jenkins), you can write a script to parse the pid from output of `jps` and kill it.